# How to improve my auto-update functionn? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, auto-update

I'm still learning VB.net and I'm now at a stage where I want to write an auto-update function, now I wrote this simple function myself, nothing fancy but I'd just like to check to see that there's no major flaws in my logic? Short of human error I think this is a nice simple way to do this.

*Note: it all works flawlessly from my testing.*

**My Function**

```
Public Function updateCheck()
        Dim CurrentVersion As String = My.Settings.currentVersion
        Dim updateURL As String = My.Settings.updateURL
        Dim WebRequest As WebClient = New WebClient
        Dim Version As String = WebRequest.DownloadString(updateURL)

        If Version = CurrentVersion Then
            MessageBox.Show("no updates available")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("An new version is available: " & Version)
        End If

    End Function
```

**updatecheck.html** file simply contains `"vx.x.x"` which sites on a web-server and the `currentVersion` string is again `"vx.x.x"`

I can't see this failing short of forgetting to change the `currentVersion` string upon an application update and it looping.

In terms of simplistic and clean code, is there anyway I can improve this? - I plan on adding some download and execute code to download an updater which un-installs and re-installs the latest version. - I'm currently using InstallShield to deploy the application.

Thanks for any suggestions/comments.

Comment: What if the website is down? WebRequest would fail to retrieve the data at all. what if the network connection is down? same problem - you will get an unhandled exception thus your program will crash. what if you have some casing issues between your current version and the one shown on the website? it will fail.

Comment: If the website is down and no internet connection then no program could auto-update? Maybe I should add an exception to check for internet connectivity? Also I assume you mean caching, that is a possibility but how can I avoid that?

Comment: Exactly. you should always catch exceptions where it is probably going to be thrown in code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to code this yourself - you should have a look at [ClickOnce deployment.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This has all the functionality you are trying to code and handles all the error cases when there is no connection, etc. It also allows for install without admin rights.

Comment: But doesn't that mean I need to buy a certificate before it's trusted to not require admin privileges?

Comment: You can use a self signed certificate - it just doesn't look as professional as a paid for one.